# How to attract/finding/interact element using selenium java for angular web

Tags: java, angular, selenium-webdriver

I am really struggling with the automation of angular web app.

I tried with simple code but still code isn't working. For example, my code is like this:

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setUp() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Driver/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        ngDriver = new NgWebDriver((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
        driver.get("https://acn-sit.dev.azlife.allianz.co.id/en/#/portal/login");
    }

    public void testInput() throws InterruptedException{
//        WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
//        WebElement input = driver.findElement(By.tagName("input"));
//        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@test-id,'username')]"));
        jsdriver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
        WebElement input   = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@test-id,'username')]"));
//        WebElement input = driver.findElement(ByAngular.model("acn-input-login-username"));
//        WebElement input = driver.findElement(ByAngular.cssContainingText("input[id='acn-input-login-username']", "Username"));
        input.sendKeys("testuser");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
```

For this element like this, using `NgWebDriver` still didn't work.

```
<input _ngcontent-qqo-c316="" required="" nxinput="" id="acn-input-login-username" test-id="acn-username" name="username" autocomplete="off" class="is-filled cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored c-input nx-input ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched" ng-reflect-required="" ng-reflect-id="acn-input-login-username" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
```

and output like this if no use ByAngular

```
 Build info: version: '4.8.2', revision: '826dbfc730'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [ca2370ae09d6d29667363691d837a822, findElement {using=xpath, value=//input[contains(@test-id,'username')]}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 113.0.5672.93, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 113.0.5672.63 (0e1a4471d5ae..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ACHMAD~1\AppData\L...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:61346}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:61346/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 113.0.5672.93, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: ca2370ae09d6d29667363691d837a822
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:193)
```

and this output if i using byAngular model etc.

```
Build info: version: '4.8.2', revision: '826dbfc730'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '19.0.2'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [ae3677a507c8aaf53657b78c56447e54, executeScript {script=var cssSelector = 'input[id='acn-input-login-username']';
var searchText = 'Username';
var using = arguments[0] || document;


  using = using || document;

  if (searchText.indexOf('__REGEXP__') === 0) {
    var match = searchText.split('__REGEXP__')[1].match(/\/(.*)\/(.*)?/);
    searchText = new RegExp(match[1], match[2] || '');
  }
  var elements = using.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);
  var matches = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
    var element = elements[i];
    var elementText = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';
    var elementMatches = searchText instanceof RegExp ?
        searchText.test(elementText) :
        elementText.indexOf(searchText) > -1;
```

Comment: Would you consider using Python instead of Java? If so, I may have a solution that requires just a few line of code.

Comment: Please specify 'isn't working'. Update your question with output/exception.

Comment: @JakobBagterp may i know solution for that using python? at least i know the flow and can read the flow what actual happen in angular web.

Comment: @pburgr ok i will add for output

Answer (score 0):

Is it correctly understood that you want to automate a browser to log in to a page?

If so, your attempt with Java and Selenium appears like a lot of code. Maybe you could consider trying with Python and [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) as an extension of Selenium?

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and you're ready to go.

```py
from browserist import Browser, LoginForm1Step, LoginCredentials

login_credentials = LoginCredentials(
    username = "testuser",
    password = "testpassword")

login_form = LoginForm1Step(
    url = "https://acn-sit.dev.azlife.allianz.co.id/en/#/portal/login",
    username_input_xpath = "//input[contains(@test-id,'username')]",
    password_input_xpath = "//input[contains(@test-id,'password')]",
    submit_button_xpath = "//xpath/to/login_button")

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.combo.log_in(login_credentials, login_form)
    browser.open.url("https://example.com/some_page")
    browser.click.button("//xpath/to/button")
```

PS: You may need to adjust some of the inputs for user name, password and [XPath](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/user-guide/xpath/intro/) to relevant elements.

You may also find [other configuration options for the login combo](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/user-guide/combo-methods/log-in/) relevant.